# The WLAN reception is worse with Linux than with Windows. How can this be?

Tags: fedora, wlan

I'm using Windows and Linux (fedora 31) simultaneously on my computer (dual boot).
I have noticed that the WLAN-reception is much worse with Linux than with Windows, even though the computer is in the same place. How can this be?

Could the problem be due to the PC settings or maybe the driver?

Has anyone ever had a similar problem and can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you just relying on the WIFI symbol that may show a worse reception? I have a openSUSE Leap laptop that can stand right next to the router and it sometimes doesn't show full reception, although I have full bandwidth. Have you compared some numbers you get from maybe ping/iperf tests etc.?

Comment: No. I have not yet compared any numbers. Only a bar is displayed at the Wlan icon (with Windows the icon is full). But also otherwise the speed is slower on Linux.

Comment: Those bars might be misleading.  I would check to see if you are having any packet loss or delayed packets.  Use a simple ping to your router to check.  Eg if your router's IP address is 192.168.1.1 then open a command prompt and type `ping 192.168.1.1`.  On windows use `ping -t 192.168.1.1`.